# How to explain the intuition of distributional moments using a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, teaching

I want to create figures to explain the meaning of the (first four) moments of a distribution (with this I mean: Mean, Variance, Skewness, Kurtosis). The goal is to use this in teaching stats.

I am not 100% sure whether this belongs here, since I'm implicitly asking two questions: How to best depict the moments *and* how to draw this in TeX and friends. Unfortunately these questions can not be be disentangled, so I'm hoping for the community's creative input here.

My first go at this is pasted below. I think this can be substantially improved upon. What is still missing is a convincing depiction of Kurtosis (i.e. one where it becomes clear that the other moments are being kept constant) and I feel that the other plots could benefit from being visually de-cluttered:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=5px]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}
First moment (Location):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        no markers
    , domain=-7.5:11.5
    , samples=100
    , ymin=0
    , axis lines*=left
    , xlabel= 
     , every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south}
    , every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
    , height=5cm
    , width=15cm
    , xtick=\empty
    , ytick=\empty
    , enlargelimits=false
    , clip=false
    , axis on top
    , grid = major
    , hide y axis
    , hide x axis
    ]


% Normal Distribution 1
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] {gauss(x, 0, 1.75)};
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(0, 0, 1.75)}
\draw [dashed, thick, blue] (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs:0, \valueA);
\node[below] at (axis cs:0, -0.02)  {\Large \textcolor{blue}{$\mu_{1}$}}; 
\draw[thick, blue] (axis cs:-0.0, -0.01) -- (axis cs:0.0, 0.01);

% Normal Distribution 2
\addplot[green, ultra thick] {gauss(x, 4, 1.75)};
\draw [dashed, thick, green] (axis cs:4, 0) -- (axis cs:4, \valueA);
\node[below] at (axis cs:4, -0.02)  {\Large \textcolor{green}{$\mu_{2}$}}; 
\draw[thick, green] (axis cs:4, -0.01) -- (axis cs:4, 0.01);

 \draw[orange, -latex, line width = 1pt] (axis cs:0,0.1) -- (axis cs:4,0.1)
                node[anchor = north east, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize] {};
                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
Second moment (Dispersion):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        no markers
    , domain=-7.5:11.5
    , samples=100
    , ymin=0
    , axis lines*=left
    , xlabel= 
    , every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south}
    , every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
    , height=5cm
    , width=15cm
    , xtick=\empty
    , ytick=\empty
    , enlargelimits=false
    , clip=false
    , axis on top
    , grid = major
    , hide y axis
    , hide x axis
    ]


% Normal Distribution 1
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] {gauss(x, 2, 1.25)};
\draw [dashed, thick, blue] (axis cs:0.85, 0) -- (axis cs:0.85, 0.20);
\draw [dashed, thick, blue] (axis cs:3.15, 0) -- (axis cs:3.15, 0.20);
\draw [dashed, latex-latex, thick, blue] (axis cs:0.9, 0.1) -- (axis cs:3.1, 0.10);
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, 0.1)  {\Large \textcolor{blue}{$\sigma_{1}$}}; 

% Normal Distribution 2
\addplot[green, ultra thick] {gauss(x, 2, 2.75)};
\draw [dashed, thick, green] (axis cs:5, 0) -- (axis cs:5, 0.083);
\draw [dashed, thick, green] (axis cs:-1, 0) -- (axis cs:-1, 0.083);
\draw [dashed, latex-latex, thick, green] (axis cs:-1, 0.05) -- (axis cs:5, 0.05);
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, 0.05)  {\Large \textcolor{green}{$\sigma_{2}$}}; 

\draw[orange, -latex, line width = 1pt] (axis cs:0.85,0.015) -- (axis cs:-1,0.015)  node[anchor = north east, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize] {};
\draw[orange, -latex, line width = 1pt] (axis cs:3.15,0.015) -- (axis cs:5,0.015)  node[anchor = north east, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize] {};
                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\Third moment (Skewness):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={gamma(\z)=
        (2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z) + 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5) + 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5) - (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920 - (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z);},
        declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = \x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta) / (\theta^\k*gamma(\k));}
]
\begin{axis}[
        no markers
    , domain=-1:10.5
    , samples=100
    , ymin=0
    , axis lines*=left
    , xlabel= 
    , every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south}
    , every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
    , height=5cm
    , width=15cm
    , xtick=\empty
    , ytick=\empty
    , enlargelimits=false
    , clip=true
    , axis on top
    , grid = major
    , hide y axis
    , hide x axis
    ]

% Normal Distribution 1
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] {gauss(x, 3.3, 1.25)};
\draw [dashed, thick, blue] (axis cs:3.3, 0) -- (axis cs:3.3, 0.33);

% Distribution 2
\addplot[green, ultra thick] {gammapdf(x,2,2)};
\draw [dashed, thick, green] (axis cs:3.32, 0) -- (axis cs:1.4, 0.167);


\draw[orange, -latex, line width = 1pt] (axis cs:3.3,0.15) -- (axis cs:2.15,0.095)  node[anchor = north east, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize] {};

\draw[thick, blue] (axis cs:3.3, 0) -- (axis cs:3.6, 0.06);
\draw[thick, green] (axis cs:3.3, 0) -- (axis cs:3.6, 0.03);
\node[right] at (axis cs:3.6, 0.06)  {\Large \textcolor{blue}{$\mu_{1}$}}; 
\node[right] at (axis cs:3.6, 0.03)  {\Large \textcolor{green}{$\mu_{2}$}}; 

                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\Fourth moment (Kurtosis):\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={gamma(\z)=
        (2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z) + 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5) + 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5) - (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920 - (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z);},
        declare function={gammapdf2(\x,\k,\theta) = (\x*\x)^(\k-1)*exp(-\x*\x/\theta) / (\theta^\k*gamma(\k));}
]
\begin{axis}[
        no markers
    , domain=-0:10
    , samples=100
    , ymin=-0.001
    , axis lines*=left
    , xlabel= 
    , every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south}
    , every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
    , height=5cm
    , width=15cm
    , xtick=\empty
    , ytick=\empty
    , enlargelimits=false
    , clip=true
    , axis on top
    , grid = major
    , hide y axis
    , hide x axis
    ]

% Normal Distribution 1
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] {gauss(x, 5, 1.25)};
\draw[dashed, thick, gray] (axis cs:5, 0) -- (axis cs:5, 0.33);

\draw[dashed,  gray] (axis cs:6.25, 0) -- (axis cs:6.25, 0.22);
\draw[dashed,  gray] (axis cs:3.75, 0) -- (axis cs:3.75, 0.22);

% Distribution 2
\draw[green, ultra thick]
     (axis cs:5, 0) ellipse [ x radius = 269, y radius = 250];   


\draw[dashed, latex-latex,  gray] (axis cs:3.75, 0.13) -- (axis cs:6.25, 0.13);
\node[below] at (axis cs:5.5, 0.13)  {\Large \textcolor{gray}{\small{$\sigma_{1}=\sigma_{2}$}}}; 

\draw[thick, gray] (axis cs:5, 0) -- (axis cs:5.3, 0.06);
\node[right] at (axis cs:5.3, 0.06)  {\Large \textcolor{gray}{\small{$\mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$}}}; 
                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear to me. You are using pgf-plots and you now want the diagramms in tikz?

Comment: I hope to have clarified the question with my edit. As I write, I'm not entirely sure this is a good fit, as I'm asking for the best way to depict something, which could in principle be answered with paint, not necessarily TeX+friends. Alternatively I might post this on stats.stackexchange.com, if people think it fits better there.

Comment: The first question is not really a good fit because you're asking for opinions. The second one is appropriate for this site. Although, I'm not sure why is it a  problem for you. I mean, you obviously know how to use `pgfplots` and `tikz` based on your code, so why is the fourth graph a problem?

Comment: Yes, the question is not how to draw it, but rather what to draw

Comment: If you want to know what to draw, `stats.stackexchange.com` might indeed be a better fit for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has clarified in comments that the question is what to draw to best explain a statistical concept and not how to draw it.